# Safest way to send an international check or wire transfer?

Tags: france, payment-cards

I am renting an apartment in France and the owner is requesting I send the deposit and, 30 days prior, the balance of the payment by check or wire transfer, in Euros. He has provided a French postal address as well as RIB, BIC, and IBAN numbers. As I understand it, bank transfers have pretty much replaced checks for transactions like this one, so the fact that the owner (a sole proprietor) is not accepting credit cards is not suspicious to me. So, how should I send this payment?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  I'm not sure that this is the appropriate forum for this question.  Feels more like money.SE.  But PayPal IMHO is better.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about secure money transfers.

Comment: I think it is on-topic because it can totally concern temporary accommodation, the same way AirBNB or hotels sellers provide a way to secure payment.

Comment: For this question, I think the security would involve that you are certain to benefit from the accommodation - in other words, wiring money using BIC/IBAN identifiers is secure, but what proof do you have that you will be able to enter and live in the place? Is your contact a professional? Maybe there are more secure ways for this deal, that's what you can ask.

Comment: If it's off-topic, feel free to delete. The owner has a day job (found him on LinkedIn) but the contract is professional-looking. I'm under the impression that Western Union transfers, once picked up, are untraceable, so if there's a method that would let me verify the identity of the recipient, that would be good, and consumer protections (if any) like with a credit card would be better.

Comment: The problem with WU, checks, and bank transfers you have no way of getting them back once they are pushed through the system.  PayPal and the like are the only way to have it secured

Comment: @Karlson: In theory yes, but a quick search shows that quite a few people have been screwed by PayPal itself and lost a lot of money to them. I would not use "PayPal" and "secure payments" in the same sentence.

Comment: I'd suggest you ask on [the Money StackExchange site](http://money.stackexchange.com/) - plenty of advice and experts there on working out the cheapest way to make international wire transfers (amongst many other topics)

Comment: @iHaveacomputer Not sure.  I am using PayPal for business on both sending and receiving end and we've lost disputes only twice.

Answer (score 3):

A wire transfer is inherently unreliable, so much so that Western Union money transfers have become the preferred scam method in London for people taking 'deposits' on apartments that don't exist! (the joys of using [Gumtree](http://www.gumtree.com/)).

A cheque at least is traceable, but then you have to put up a fight to get the money back if need be, and it's hard to argue, because after all, you sent him the cheque!

It's pretty rare that people require payment upfront, although to be fair I did that for a place I rented last year in Australia, which was fine (AirBnb). At least that was a lot easier to check their references.

Consider [reading something like this -a guide to spotting a scam when renting](http://discover.realestate.com.au/renting-sharing/how-to/how-to-protect-yourself-from-rental-scams).  Have you read reviews of the place? Know anyone local who can confirm that it exists?

It's understandable that he's not accepting credit cards, he may get charged extra for accepting them.

Finally, ask if he'd accept a deposit for now, and the full amount later - that at least minimises your loss if it is a scam.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "unreliable". Western Union will absolutely reliably hand your money to the intended recipient. Whether that recipient will have an apartment waiting for you on the other hand is very doubtful.